# AngularJS UI Router caches templateUrl, MVC Controller not called

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

My ui-router is setup as follows:

```
var editMe = {
        name: 'edit.editme',
        url: '/users/edit/:Id',
        parent: edit,
        templateUrl: function (params) {
            return '/users/edit/' + params.Id;
        },
        controller: 'EditMeController'
    }
```

This calls an Action method on my MVC Controller with the correct Id which returns user info. After I have changed some values, I want to navigate to this user again. The templateUrl is now cached, and my MVC controller method does not get called again, resulting in stale data returned. Any idea as to how I can prevent this caching or ensure that the MVC action method gets called again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution. templateUrl gets cached after the first load, thereafter the MVC controller won't get called again.

Using templateProvider and $http.get resolves this:

```
var editMe = {
        name: 'edit.editme',
        url: '/users/edit/:Id',
        parent: edit,
        templateProvider: function ($stateParams, $http) {
            return $http.get('/users/edit/' + $stateParams.Id)
                .then(function (result) {                        
                    return result.data;
                });
        },            
        controller: 'EditMeController'
    }
```

The $http.get ensures the MVC controller method gets called everytime, resulting in 'fresh' HTML being returned to display.